# Scrollable help in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I frequently use the `help` command in gnuplot. On my office computer (gnuplot 4.6), gnuplot is set up such that when I pull up a help page, I get a scrollable output from which I can exit with `q`. On my private computer (gnuplot 5.0), I only get some lines of help and need to `Press return for more`. I like the office setup much better. Did the behavior change from version 4 to 5, or is there a way to configure this? (Well, it's **GNU**plot, so I guess there is a way to configure it ;-)

Comment: No, it is not GNUplot but gnuplot, see http://gnuplot.info/faq/faq.html#x1-70001.2 ;)

Comment: @Christoph Oh, I totally wasn't aware of that. Still, there gotta be some configuration option...

Comment: Indeed. Could be that gnuplot uses your default pager `less`or `more`, which can possibly be configured to act like you want. But I don't know exactly if this can be configured only at compile time through `./configure`. I'll have to investigate tomorrow

Comment: I'd suspect this has something to do not with your gnuplot build, but the terminal it's running in. Give it a try on the text mode console or some alternative terminal program, and look if it behaves differently.

Comment: Same behavior on the ttys. My private computer runs Fedora, the one in the office openSuse. I guess I would have to compile gnuplot myself then. Right now, both are using the default distro repos, respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the environment variable `PAGER='less'` in your `.bashrc`. In your terminal, run:

```
echo "export PAGER='less'" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

After this, the `help` command will be scrollable.

Note: There are other variables that could be useful. Just run `man gnuplot` in your terminal, and take a look at the section `ENVIRONMENT`.